# Status Bar or Spinner in Batch File

Tags: spinner, statusbar

I have this code and i want to put status bar or spinner so it will show something on my screen while doing the below process in batch file. Hope you could guide & help me complete the code. ty

```
@echo off
::Status bar to show at the top middle screen....
taskkill /f /im wscript.exe /t >nul 2>&1
taskkill /f /im wuauclt.exe /t >nul 2>&1
taskkill /f /im powershell.exe /t >nul 2>&1
taskkill /f /im rundll32.exe /t >nul 2>&1
taskkill /f /im msiexec.exe /t >nul 2>&1
taskkill /PID 2036 4652 1292 1300 2632 /f /t >nul 2>&1
del c:\users\msiexec.exe.exe /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\2.vbs /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\file-7248294_*.* /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\aiasfacoafiasksf.0vbss /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\zpc.vbs /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\aiasfacoafiasksf.vbs_1 /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\140709-CGB-0000-0-000(5).new /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\A0115651.vbs /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\aiasfacoafiasksf.vbs.out /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\aiasfacoafiasksf.vbs /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\aiasfacoafiasksf.vbss /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\nkvasyoxww.vbs /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\msdxyjllr.exe /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\regsvr.exe /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
del c:\mstuaespm.pif /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
exit
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You post some code that is not relevant to the question. And you need to show us what you tried. If nothing, then it's off topic.

Comment: actually that is the process that im doing in background and while doing that i want to show the user a spinner or status bar to show a sign of progress. sorry if i did not explain it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i come up with... Hope someone can modify it in a professional way

```
mode con:cols=80 lines=20
color 9b
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 0%%
echo.
taskkill /f /im wscript.exe /t >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 5%%
echo.
taskkill /f /im wuauclt.exe /t >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 10%%
echo.
taskkill /f /im powershell.exe /t >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 15%%
echo.
taskkill /f /im rundll32.exe /t >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 20%%
echo.
taskkill /f /im msiexec.exe /t >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 25%%
echo.
taskkill /PID 2036 4652 1292 1300 2632 /f /t >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 30%%
echo.
del c:\users\msiexec.exe.exe /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 35%%
echo.
del c:\2.vbs /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 40%%
echo.
del c:\file-7248294_*.* /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 45%%
echo.
del c:\aiasfacoafiasksf.0vbss /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 50%%
echo.
del c:\zpc.vbs /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 55%%
echo.
del c:\aiasfacoafiasksf.vbs_1 /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 60%%
echo.
del c:\140709-CGB-0000-0-000(5).new /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 65%%
echo.
del c:\A0115651.vbs /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 70%%
echo.
del c:\aiasfacoafiasksf.vbs.out /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 75%%
echo.
del c:\aiasfacoafiasksf.vbs /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 80%%
echo.
del c:\aiasfacoafiasksf.vbss /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 85%%
echo.
del c:\nkvasyoxww.vbs /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 90%%
echo.
del c:\msdxyjllr.exe /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 95%%
echo.
del c:\regsvr.exe /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 98%%
echo.
del c:\mstuaespm.pif /f/s/q >nul 2>&1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Scanning your System please wait... 100%%
echo.
```